# BokehUserWarning and problem with pandas_datareader in python

Tags: python, bokeh, pandas-datareader

I am trying to plot a chart with bokeh.plotting from stock data gotten from data.DataReader using the pandas_datareader module.

Issue one: the data retrieved is in pandas.Index and not pandas.DatetimeIndex

Issue two: I receive a BokehWarning

The code1:

```
import os
from pandas_datareader import data
from datetime import datetime as dt

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

os.environ["ALPHAVANTAGE_API_KEY"] = "E____secret____4"

hours_12 = 12*60*60*1000
start = dt(2016,3,1)
end = dt(2016,3,10)

f = data.DataReader('GOOG','av-daily',start,end,api_key=os.getenv('ALPHAVANTAGE_API_KEY'))

#f
#f.loc['2016-03-09']

f.index
```

Output:

```
Index(['2016-03-01', '2016-03-02', '2016-03-03', '2016-03-04', '2016-03-07',
       '2016-03-08', '2016-03-09', '2016-03-10'],
      dtype='object')
```

Note that index was meant to be DatetimeIndex([...) not Index

the value for f is:

```
            open    high         low     close   volume
2016-03-01  703.62  718.8100    699.77  718.81  2151419
2016-03-02  719.00  720.0000    712.00  718.85  1629003
2016-03-03  718.68  719.4500    706.02  712.42  1957974
2016-03-04  714.99  716.4900    706.02  710.89  1972077
2016-03-07  706.90  708.0912    686.90  695.16  2988026
2016-03-08  688.59  703.7900    685.34  693.97  2058471
2016-03-09  698.47  705.6800    694.00  705.24  1421515
2016-03-10  708.12  716.4400    703.36  712.82  2833525
```

Code 2:

```
p = figure(x_axis_type='datetime',width=1000,height=400, title="CandleStick Chart")

p.rect(x=f.index[f.close > f.open],y=(f.open + f.close)/2, width=hours_12, height=abs(f.open-f.close))
output_file("cs.html")
show(p)
```

Output:

```
BokehUserWarning: ColumnDataSource's columns must be of the same length. Current lengths: ('x', 4), ('y', 8)
BokehUserWarning: ColumnDataSource's columns must be of the same length. Current lengths: ('height', 8), ('x', 4), ('y', 8)
```

The bokeh output was a blank slate, it is not suppose to be. I followed a tutorial and it seemed to work in the tutorial (The tutorial is a bit outdated though)
Kindly help out and be gentle with the answers or not. It has been an headache

Comment: You're filtering values that go into `x` but you aren't filtering the ones that go into `y` and `height`. That's why the length is different.

Comment: @Eugene Pakhomov thanks for the reply, I noticed that too; but, I don't know why it worked in the tutorial.(https://www.udemy.com/course/the-python-mega-course/) with the same values.

Comment: I can't view the code of the tutorial because it's behind the paywall. But if that's 100% the same code then it's a bad tutorial that uses incorrect code that just happened to work with some particular data.

Comment: It was not bad really, I was just impatient, the tutorial actually helped me to resolve most of the issue in later videos. I guess at the time the module was working, now it is deprecated. The tutorial was actually really helpful, won't want to get my sensei in trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by changing the data source from Alpha Vantage to Yahoo Finance. I didn't use yahoo directly as the source from data.DataReader module because it was deprecated. Turns out that yahoo finance created a separate module called yfinance.

```
from pandas_datareader import data
from datetime import datetime as dt
import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override() #this enables your code use yfinance instead of pdr
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

hours_12 = 12*60*60*1000
start = dt(2016,3,1)
end = dt(2016,3,10)
df=data.get_data_yahoo(tickers="GOOG", start=start, end=end)
```

yfinance create the pandas.DatetimeIndex instead of the pandas.Index data by alpha vantage. This creates the graph but there is still the BokehWarning

To resolve the BokehWarning issue and ensure your chart is accurate and consistent, I created new columns in the df by doing this

```
def status(open,close):
    if open < close:
        value="Profit"
    elif open > close:
        value="Loss"
    else: value="Equal"
    return value


df['Status'] = [status(open,close) for open,close in zip(df.Open,df.Close)]
df['Middle_y'] = (df.Open+df.Close)/2
df['Height'] = abs(df.Close-df.Open)
```

You can then go ahead and create your chart by adding the variables.

```
p = figure(x_axis_type='datetime',width=1000,height=400, title="CandleStick Chart")

p.rect(x=df.index[df.Status =="Profit"],y=df.Middle_y[df.Status=='Profit'], width=hours_12,
       height=df.Height[df.Status=="Profit"],fill_color="green", line_color="black")

p.rect(x=df.index[df.Status =="Loss"],y=df.Middle_y[df.Status=='Loss'], width=hours_12,
       height=df.Height[df.Status=="Loss"],fill_color="red", line_color="black")


output_file("cs.html")
show(p)
```

I hope this help anyone that encounters the same difficulty in the future